# How integrate scorm courses to my website

Tags: javascript, scorm

I have scorm course, this is a package with [next files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju1FR.png)

I can upload it to scorm cloud (using scorm driver) and launch it here. But I need to display this course on my own website. And I don't understand how to do this.

Should I use some scorm player? [Here](https://scorm.com/scorm-player/) is said than I can use scorm cloud, but it doesn't fit for me (or i don't understand something).

Or should I to use scorm wrapper? But how use it for display course.

In feature I will get scorm packages from server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic recipe for SCORM (Build vs Buy) -

- backend api (Name your flavor NodeJS, PHP, ASP.NET etc...)
- A database (SQL/NOSQL)
- frontend HTML/CSS/JS
- Content launches in IFRAME, new window, tab (depending on preference)
- Requires a SCORM Runtime Environment (RTE) for SCORM 1.2 or 2004 depending (JavaScript). This is mostly a paid option or you'll need to roll your own.  This enforces the SCORM Specification for each student attempt.  This is called a CMI Object.  It's comprised of scoring, interactions, objectives etc.  This is the core of what your asking for, but does have dependancies on the backend for saving student attempts, getting student attempts and managing the history of student attempts.
- Content (Imported via zip called a CAM Content Aggregation model) complete with imsmanifest.xml.  This can be done thru Upload or manually placing the content on the server.
- XML Parsing, XSD Validation optional
- This builds your Table of Contents you'll display in your Lesson Viewer.  Consider placing all imported content into Assignments so you can Assign them to students.  This also assumes you have User Management.  If you don't, you're building that too.

And this is all just considering time to market.  If you are in the Aquire / Buy category -

Free: Moodle (SCORM 1.2, limited or no SCORM 2004)

All other options I'm aware of start to have subscription, seat or one time payment options.  Keep in mind, these were created from 2001-2009.  I want you to get in a time machine and go back in time and remember the state of JavaScript ;).  So something to watch out for depending on what you goals are.

I will plug the fact I sell the SCORM Runtime API only for integration with a existing site but you must bring the surrounding API support, Database and Lesson Viewer (I provide examples of this, documentation and support). But, obviously depending on your goals as you Google this issue you'll realize this "ask" ranges from thousands to hundreds of thousands of dollars vs. spending 2 years reading white paper specifications and sorting all this out.

My site https://cybercussion.com has plenty of info as well as my GitHub open source project for Content Development https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot/wiki which can highlight some of the content side of interfacing a LMS.